# how to add product price based on two dropdown values in magento configurable product?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product, price

I am using `magento 1.9`. I would like to add a configurable product with price based on two dropdown values,

I have two attributes `Thickness` and `Size`.

Thickness dropdown with values `1/2 Inch` and `1/4 Inch`.

Size dropdown with values `8"x12"` and `12"x16"`

I would like to assign price like,

```
1/2 Inch X 8"x12" = 42$

1/2 Inch X 12"x16" = 62$

1/4 Inch X 8"x12" = 54$

1/4 Inch X 12"x16" = 82$
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Although not the official answer I prefer to install [SCP](https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple) as this will then take the price from the simple products. It's far easier to understand than the official way but that's just my opinion

Comment: there is no direct option add product price based on two dropdown values ?